# Injectivity of a convex combination of squares $A^*A$ in $\ell^\infty$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, convexity

Consider two operators $A,B: \ell^p \to \ell^p$ ([defined and]bounded for all $p \in [1,\infty]$) as well as their adjoints $A^*,B^*:\ell^p \to \ell^p$. Assume $A^*A$ and $B^*B$ have trivial kernel and look at $C_t = tA^*A + (1-t)B^*B$ for $t \in ]0,1[$.

If $p=2$ it's a fairly simple exercise to check that $C_t$ is also injective: look at
$$\langle f \mid C_t f\rangle = t\langle f \mid A^*A f\rangle + (1-t)\langle f \mid B^*B f\rangle = t\|Af\|^2_{\ell^2} + (1-t) \|Bf\|^2_{\ell^2}$$
By injectivity of $A$ and $B$ (which follows from the injectivity of $A^*A$ and $B^*B$), the RHS is $>0$ as soon as $f \neq 0$. In particular, $C_tf \neq 0$. Since the inclusion $\ell^p \subset \ell^2$ holds for $p<2$, the injectivity $C_t$ follows for $p<2$ too). My question is regarding the other extreme:

**Question:** Is $C_t:\ell^p \to \ell^p$ still injective for $p = \infty$?

For the actual operators $A$ and $B$ I am looking at this [seems to] hold, but I believe there should be a counterexample in this generality. Apologies in advance if this is a well-established question...

Comment: What is the definition of "adjoint"? The composition $A^*A$ can be defined only for $p=2$.

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan if $A$ maps $\ell^p$ to $\ell^p$ for all $p$, this is well defined

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan if $A: X \to Y$ is a bounded operator, then $A^*: Y^* \to X^*$ is defined by: given $\tilde{y} \in Y^*$ one has, for any $x \in X$, $\langle A^* \tilde{y} \mid x \rangle = \langle \tilde{y} \mid Ax \rangle$. Since $A$ is **defined and bounded** for any $p$ then so is $A^*$. Hence $A^*A$ makes sense, although I'll admit it is not common to see. (You could argue about $A^*A$ being defined on $\ell^1$ because I did not explicitly mention that $A$ was defined and bounded on $c_0$, but then $c_0 \subset \ell^\infty$ and boundedness as well as injectivity pass to $c_0$.)

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan Here is a probably less pedantic definition of "adjoint" for Banach spaces. An element $\tilde{y} \in Y^*$ is a linear bounded map $\tilde{y}:Y \to \mathbb{R}$ and $A$ is a linear bounded map $A:X \to Y$. Then $A^*\tilde{y}$ is the composition of $\tilde{y}$ and $A$, i.e. $A^*\tilde{y} = \tilde{y} \circ A$. Since $\tilde{y} \circ A$ is a linear bounded map from $X \to \mathbb{R}$ it belongs to $X^*$. (Just in case it makes things more readable: one can replace bounded by continuous everywhere.)

Comment: @ARG: These explanations are fine, but I do think Meisam has a point. First of all, $A^*A$ probably really means $(A_{p'})^*A_p$ (that is, one is composing not with the adjoint of the first operator, but with the adjoint of its version on the dual space). Also, how exactly does that work when $p=\infty$ and the dual isn't $\ell^1$?

Comment: @ChristianRemling There are operators which have the same definition indenpendently of $p$. If it makes things clearer, here is another way of looking at the set-up: I have an operator $A:\ell^\infty \to \ell^\infty$ which is bounded. This operator is also defined on $\ell^1$ (since $\ell^1 \subset \ell^\infty$). Furthermore, this operator has the property that it is bounded $\ell^1 \to \ell^1$. Because of this, $A^*$ is also bounded as an operator from $\ell^\infty \to \ell^\infty$. Hence $A^*A$ makes sense. Should I edit the OP? The dual of $\ell^\infty$ plays no role in this question.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Perhaps a simple example of such an operator (close to the one which inspired the question) is to look at the shift $A$. This operator shifts the sequence by adding a 0 at the beginning. It is defined and bounded for all $p$. It has an adjoint $A^*$ which is also defined and bounded for all $p$ [it's the deletion of the first element of the sequence]. Hence $A^*A$ makes sense for all $p$. (Now in this case $A^*A$ has a kernel so it's not a perfect fit for the question.)

Comment: @ARG: Thanks for clarifying. You are right, there is no problem for $p=\infty$. Instead, I should have asked about $p=1$, which you already addressed in your earlier comment (we use that $\ell^1=c^*_0$, $c_0\subseteq\ell^{\infty}$ isometrically).

Comment: Just some side notes (to those reading this far):(1)the fact that $A$ is bounded $\ell^\infty \to \ell^\infty$ and also $\ell^1 \to \ell^1$ implies that it is bounded $\ell^p \to \ell^p$ for any $p$ (thanks to Riesz-Thorin interpolation).(2)though $\ell^2$ is dense in $\ell^p$ (for $p<\infty$) it is not obvious to me that the question has a positive answer for $p \in ]2,\infty[$. For $p=\infty$ a negative answer seems even more likely (whence the idea of going to this extreme).(3)correction to the above $A^*A$ (with $A=$shift) has no kernel since $A^*A = I$; it's $AA^*$ which has a kernel.